# add-resource Data Source with wildfly-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, jboss

In the first run of maven clean install, the driver and data source and the application are deployed successfully. But when performing another maven clean install, the log informs that the data source is already registered.

How to solve this problem, I already looked in the documentation and I did not think how to prevent this re-implantation of datasource

**POM.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.sistema</groupId>
  <artifactId>sgr</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven-compiler.version>3.3</maven-compiler.version>
    <maven-war-plugin.version>2.6</maven-war-plugin.version>
    <properties-maven-plugin.version>1.0.0</properties-maven-plugin.version>
    <wildfly-maven-plugin.version>1.1.0.Beta1</wildfly-maven-plugin.version>
    <mysql-connector-java.version>5.1.39</mysql-connector-java.version>
    <flyway-maven-plugin.version>4.0.2</flyway-maven-plugin.version>
    <primefaces-version>6.0</primefaces-version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- MySql Conector -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql-connector-java.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>           
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>../src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <finalName>sgr-${project.version}</finalName>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-compiler.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>${java.version}</source>
          <target>${java.version}</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-war-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${wildfly-maven-plugin.version}</version>
        <executions>
            <!-- Add Driver JDBC MySql no servidor -->
            <execution>
                <id>deploy-driver</id>
                <phase>install</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                    <version>${mysql-connector-java.version}</version>
                    <name>mysql-connector-java-${mysql-connector-java.version}</name>
                    <driver-name>mysql-connector-java-${mysql-connector-java.version}</driver-name>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                  <goal>deploy-artifact</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>

            <!-- Add data source da aplicação no servidor -->
            <execution>
                <id>add-datasource</id>
                <phase>install</phase>
                <configuration>
                  <force>false</force>
                  <address>subsystem=datasources,data-source=SGRDS</address>
                  <resources>
                      <resource>
                          <properties>
                              <jndi-name>java:jboss/datasources/SGRDS</jndi-name>
                              <enable>true</enable>
                              <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost/sgrdb?useSSL=false</connection-url>
                              <driver-name>mysql-connector-java-5.1.39_com.mysql.jdbc.Driver_5_1</driver-name>
                              <user-name>root</user-name>
                              <password>2cs2dlmf</password>
                          </properties>
                      </resource>
                  </resources>
                  <retryFailedDeploymentCount>1</retryFailedDeploymentCount>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>add-resource</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>

            <!-- Realiza deploy no servidor e install da aplicação no repositório -->
            <execution>
              <id>deploy</id>
              <phase>install</phase>
              <goals>
                  <goal>deploy</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>              
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

**force = true ERRO data source is already registered.**

**false = false**

**ERRO**

```
ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."sgr-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".WeldInstantiator: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."sgr-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".WeldInstantiator: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYWELD0041: WeldContainer is not started
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldBootstrapService.getBeanManager(WeldBootstrapService.java:183)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldComponentService.start(WeldComponentService.java:97)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    ... 3 more

16:23:23,658 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."sgr-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".WeldInstantiator: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."sgr-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".WeldInstantiator: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYWELD0041: WeldContainer is not started
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldBootstrapService.getBeanManager(WeldBootstrapService.java:183)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldComponentService.start(WeldComponentService.java:97)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    ... 3 more

16:23:23,658 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."sgr-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".WeldInstantiator: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."sgr-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".WeldInstantiator: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYWELD0041: WeldContainer is not started
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldBootstrapService.getBeanManager(WeldBootstrapService.java:183)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldComponentService.start(WeldComponentService.java:97)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    ... 3 more

16:23:23,658 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."sgr-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".CdiValidatorFactoryService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."sgr-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".CdiValidatorFactoryService: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYWELD0041: WeldContainer is not started
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldBootstrapService.getBeanManager(WeldBootstrapService.java:207)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.CdiValidatorFactoryService.start(CdiValidatorFactoryService.java:77)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    ... 3 more

16:23:23,659 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."sgr-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener".WeldInstantiator: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."sgr-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener".WeldInstantiator: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYWELD0041: WeldContainer is not started
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldBootstrapService.getBeanManager(WeldBootstrapService.java:183)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldComponentService.start(WeldComponentService.java:97)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    ... 3 more

16:23:23,659 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."sgr-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener".WeldInstantiator: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."sgr-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener".WeldInstantiator: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYWELD0041: WeldContainer is not started
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldBootstrapService.getBeanManager(WeldBootstrapService.java:183)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldComponentService.start(WeldComponentService.java:97)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    ... 3 more

16:23:23,659 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."sgr-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".WeldInstantiator: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."sgr-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".WeldInstantiator: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYWELD0041: WeldContainer is not started
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldBootstrapService.getBeanManager(WeldBootstrapService.java:183)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldComponentService.start(WeldComponentService.java:97)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    ... 3 more

16:23:23,661 WARN  [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000004: Failure during stop of service jboss.deployment.unit."sgr-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".WeldStartService: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYWELD0041: WeldContainer is not started
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldStartService.stop(WeldStartService.java:121)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StopTask.stopService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2056)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StopTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2017)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**New Pom.xml** And same error  **WFLYWELD0041: WeldContainer is not started**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.sistema</groupId>
  <artifactId>sgr</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>     

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <wildfly.version>10.1.0.Final</wildfly.version>
    <maven-compiler.version>3.3</maven-compiler.version>
    <maven-war-plugin.version>2.6</maven-war-plugin.version>
    <properties-maven-plugin.version>1.0.0</properties-maven-plugin.version>
    <wildfly-maven-plugin.version>1.1.0.Beta1</wildfly-maven-plugin.version>
    <mysql-connector-java.version>5.1.39</mysql-connector-java.version>
    <flyway-maven-plugin.version>4.0.2</flyway-maven-plugin.version>
    <primefaces-version>6.0</primefaces-version>
  </properties>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>         
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-javaee7-with-tools</artifactId>
            <version>${wildfly.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
        <artifactId>wildfly-spec-api</artifactId>
        <version>${wildfly.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
     </dependency>

     <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
       <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
       <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>   

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql-connector-java.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>  
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>  
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>  
        <version>${primefaces-version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>        
    <finalName>sgr-${project.version}</finalName>
    <resources>      
       <resource>
           <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
           <filtering>true</filtering>
       </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-compiler.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>${java.version}</source>
          <target>${java.version}</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-war-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${wildfly-maven-plugin.version}</version>          
        <executions>
            <!-- Add Driver JDBC MySql no servidor -->
            <execution>
                <id>deploy-driver</id>
                <phase>install</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                    <version>${mysql-connector-java.version}</version>
                    <name>mysql-connector-java-${mysql-connector-java.version}</name>
                    <driver-name>mysql-connector-java-${mysql-connector-java.version}</driver-name>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                  <goal>deploy-artifact</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>

            <!-- Add data source da aplicação no servidor -->
            <execution>
                <id>add-datasource</id>
                <phase>install</phase>
                <configuration>
                  <force>false</force>
                  <address>subsystem=datasources,data-source=SGRDS</address>
                  <resources>
                      <resource>
                          <properties>
                              <jndi-name>java:jboss/datasources/SGRDS</jndi-name>
                              <enable>true</enable>
                              <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost/sgrdb?useSSL=false</connection-url>
                              <driver-name>mysql-connector-java-5.1.39_com.mysql.jdbc.Driver_5_1</driver-name>
                              <user-name>root</user-name>
                              <password>2cs2dlmf</password>
                          </properties>
                      </resource>
                  </resources>
                  <retryFailedDeploymentCount>1</retryFailedDeploymentCount>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>add-resource</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
            <!-- Realiza deploy no servidor e install da aplicação no repositório -->
            <execution>
              <id>deploy</id>
              <phase>install</phase>
              <goals>
                  <goal>deploy</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${flyway-maven-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
            <configFile>${project.build.directory}/classes/flyway.properties</configFile>
            <url>${flyway.url}</url>
            <user>${flyway.user}</user>
            <password>${flyway.password}</password>
            <schemas>
                <schema>${flyway.schemas}</schema>
            </schemas>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

**LOG ERRO MAVEN**

The error occurs after performing maven install the second time, the first time it occurs successfully.

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 17.461 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-12-12T20:45:05-02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/48M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:1.1.0.Beta1:add-resource (add-datasource) on project sgr: Could not execute goal add-resource. Reason: Resource [
[ERROR] ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
[ERROR] ("data-source" => "SGRDS")
[ERROR] ] already exists.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the [force](https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/add-resource-mojo.html#force) :)

Your configuration should look like this:

```
    <!-- Add data source da aplicação no servidor -->
    <execution>
        <id>add-datasource</id>
        <phase>install</phase>
        <configuration>
          <force>true</force> <!-- or false, not sure -->
          ...
    </execution>
```

I'm not sure tough if you have to set it to true or false. The documentaiton says that you should set it to true but it is the default value, maybe you can try with false.

Comment: Davide. Deixando a força como verdadeiro ocorreu o mesmo erro, como falso apresentou um novo erro que inseri na minha pergunta.

Comment: It seems force=false solved your initial problem. This highlighted the one you are having now. It might be something wrong in the configuration of the CDI, do you think you can publish the project somewhere (oir the part that generates the error) so that one can have a look at it? Github would be ideal.

Comment: Davide, I edited my question with my new pom. In the documentation it informs no further configuration to use the CDI with Wildfly, So I was in doubt because of this mistake, view according to the session 18.1. http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/environments.html#_using_weld_with_wildfly
My project Github https://github.com/Gervasios/sgr

Comment: At first glance, this line in the pom seems wrong:     `<sourceDirectory>../src/main/java</sourceDirectory>`, I think you don't need it. Are you sure the generate WAR is correct?

Comment: Thank you Davide, I'm going to remove this line and take the test. The war is being generated normally.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I removed the line from my pom. The same problem occurred while building the project by maven.

Comment: I noticed that the error only occurs when I perform maven install for the second time on. The first install is successful, the others are not. Now I was doubtful. In maven's log it informs the following error, which I informed in my question